# How to register Field Handler class with Migrate module

Tags: 7, files, migrations

I'm trying to use the [migrate](http://drupal.org/projects/migrate) module to import some [video](http://drupal.org/projects/video) fields. I'm assuming that I'll need to write an extension to the `MigrateFileFieldHandler`. I set up a shell class based on what I saw in the `MigrateImageFieldHandler` (which is a subclass of `MigrateFileFieldHandler`), however my class doesn't seem to get loaded.

My guess is that I need to register my Field Handler somewhere, somehow, but I can't find any instructions or examples anywhere. I know that I register Migrations in the `hook_migrate_api` but I can't find how or where I need to register Field Handlers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this blog post it looks like you register the field type from within your custom class:
http://openconcept.ca/blog/mmallett/migrating-data-using-drupals-migrate-module

as such:

```
class MigrateCUSTOMFIELDNAMEFieldHandler extends MigrateFieldHandler {
  public function __construct() {
    $this->registerTypes(array('email'));
  }
// more stuff in your class ...
```

Without such information migrate usually just silently ignores the field, or try to work with it in any way. The same rule for an improperly named/implemented Migration class -- you just don't see it in `drush ms`.

**EDIT:**

From the blog post, actually from MigrateExtras README:

> The Migrate Extras module provides extensions to Migrate
>   (http://drupal.org/project/migrate) to support various contributed
>   modules. The ideal place to implement migration support for a
>   contributed module is in that module. That way, the migration support
>   is always self-consistent with the current module implementation -
>   it's not practical for the migrate_extras module to keep up with
>   changes to all other contrib modules. Support for contributed modules
>   may be added to migrate_extras for two reasons - if the module's
>   maintainer does not accept a patch providing migration support, or as
>   an intermediate step before submitting such a patch to the other
>   module.
>
> In cases where modules supported by migrate_extras end up implementing
>   the support themselves, you could at least temporarily end up with
>   redundant implementations. The extra implementation may be disabled at
>   admin/content/migrate/configure.

Anyway, if you then look at:
http://drupalcode.org/project/migrate_extras.git/blob/9843c3b2c003e8bd19bb370e6eb6b2264f13eca1:/migrate_extras.migrate.inc

They declare their migrate API integration thus:

```
/*
 * Implementation of hook_migrate_api().
 */
function migrate_extras_migrate_api() {
  $api = array(
    'api' => 2,
    'destination handlers' => array(
      'MigratePathautoHandler',
      'MigrateExtrasNodeFlagHandler',
      'MigrateExtrasUserFlagHandler',
    ),
    'field handlers' => array(
      'MigrateAddressFieldHandler',
      'MigrateCckPhoneHandler',
      'MigrateGeoFieldHandler',
      'MigrateIntervalFieldHandler',
      'MigrateNameHandler',
      'MigrateMediaFieldHandler',
    )
  );
  return $api;
}
```

You probably want to list your FieldHanlder in a similar fashion (but with your class name). You probably also want to add it to the `files[]` array of your module so it is autoloaded and Migrate sees it.

Your new FieldHanlder should be listed at admin/content/migrate/configure

... if you read the blog post provided, it explains this oddity of FieldHandlers ...

Comment: That's within the FieldHandler code and what I'm saying is that my FieldHandler code is never called. I've got `$this->registerTypes(array('video'));` in my FieldHandler class, but the my FieldHandler class is never instantiated.

Comment: see my edit, it should fix your problem.